# angular2 i18n Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: angular, internationalization, package.json

I am using angular2.
I used [this project](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-webpack-starter-and-angular2-highcharts) for start application.

To implement multi-language support followed [this documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html)

Steps :
1) Execute command

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-server --save
```

Output:

> +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-rc.5 `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@4.0.2
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>   (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch" :"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN @angular/core@2.1.1 requires a
>   peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @angular/forms@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.4 but none
>   was installed. npm WARN @angular/forms@2.2.4 requires a peer of
>   @angular/common@2.2.4 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @angular/http@2.1.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was
>   installed. npm WARN @angular/router@3.1.1 requires a peer of
>   rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.4 requires a peer of tslint@^3.9.0 but none was
>   installed. npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.4 requires a peer of
>   @angular/compiler@~2.2.0 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.2.0 but
>   none was installed. npm WARN tslint-loader@2.1.5 requires a peer of
>   tslint@^3.0.0 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.4.1
>   but none was installed. npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.1 requires
>   a peer of @angular/core@2.4.1 but none was installed.

2) Execute command "./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n"
 It gives me below error

> C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak3\PathTrak>"./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n"
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
>       at Function.Extractor.create (C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak3\PathTrak\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extractor
>   .js:69:45)
>       at extract (C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak3\PathTrak\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extract_i18n.js:7:34)
>       at Object.main (C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak3\PathTrak\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:47:16)
>       at Object. (C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak3\PathTrak\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extract_i18n.js:
>   14:9)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10) Extraction failed

I am not able to implkement i18n due to this error.
Please find below dependancies in package.json file

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.1",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.4.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.17"
  }
```

Is it version issue in package.json file?
Kindly help

Thanks,
Sardar Nale

**-------------------------------------Modification--------------------**

I removed node_modules folder and  tried to update package.json as follows , UNMET dpendancy problem resolved but while running it gives error as 
**Error**

```
C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak>npm start

> angular2-webpack-starter@5.1.1 start C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak
> npm run server:dev


> angular2-webpack-starter@5.1.1 server:dev C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak
> webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/

keywords if/then/else require v5 option

C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak\config\webpack.common.js:178
      new ForkCheckerPlugin(),
      ^
TypeError: ForkCheckerPlugin is not a constructor
    at module.exports (C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak\config\webpack.common.js:178:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak\config\webpack.dev.js:23:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at requireConfig (C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:98:18)
    at C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:111:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at module.exports (C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:109:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:190:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server:de
v"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-webpack-starter@5.1.1 server:dev: `webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch
--content-base src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-webpack-starter@5.1.1 server:dev script 'webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progres
s --profile --watch --content-base src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-webpack-starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-webpack-starter@5.1.1 start: `npm run server:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-webpack-starter@5.1.1 start script 'npm run server:dev'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-webpack-starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run server:dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Projects\temp\PathTrak12\PathTrak\npm-debug.log
```

**package.json file**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.4.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.38",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.0.0-beta.17",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "1.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "parse5": "^2.2.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
   "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^4.0.0-dev.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.2.0-rc.0",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~2.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259979/how-to-execute-ng-xi18n-without-typeerror-cannot-read-property-create-of-unde

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's just a mismatch in your **angular versions**. You should stick with the same version for every `@angular` package (except the router, it will be 1 major version higher *until angular 4 is released*).

With your...

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-server --save
```

... it seems you've got at least `@angular/compiler-cli` at 2.**4.1** and probably and `@angular/platform-server` at 2.4.1. Since you've set the **other** `@angular` packages to a fixed version of 2.**1.1** there will be some conflicts.

Note: The docs will always assume that you are on the latest (stable) angular version.

So how to fix it...

---

### 1. installing the old packages

You can just install the old packages by adding `@angular/compiler-cli` & `@angular/platform-server` to fixed **2.1.1** in your `package.json` (don't forget to remove the caret (^) here). Then remove your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.

---

### 2. ...or updating the other packages

The other option is that you update your other`@angular` packages also to the most recent 2.4.1 version. Here you'll have to replace your **2.1.1** with the **2.4.1** in your `package.json` (except the router that would be **3.4.1**).
Then remove your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.

Here you will might run into some other issues depending on your app... You might want to check the [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) first.

---

FYI: when you are installing a new `@angular` package to your project try always to stick with the version you are using right now. To install a specific version in your case it would have been (note the `@2.1.1`):

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli@2.1.1 @angular/platform-server@2.1.1 --save
```

...or updating all to the new version ;-)

Comment: Could you please check modification part in question. I have removed node_modules folder and updated package.json and done npm install. At the time of running it gives me error. Kindly help.

Comment: regarding your updated error, the problem seems that you are using the `awesome-typescript-loader` package at 3.x.x and it looks like that they removed the `ForkCheckerPlugin` in there (see [this](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/274) ticket). So you'll have to modify your webpack config.I get the impression that you'll probably be better off using the [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for your projects. Take a look, it may spare you some headaches :-)